# BAN logic - deriving freshness of a message

Tags: security, logic, network-protocols

A quick question regarding BAN logic.

Say I have derived that A believes B said {Kr}Ka

I already know that fresh(Ka).

Can I then conclude that as fresh(Ka) then {Kr}Ka is also fresh.

In a nutshell my question is: if I have a message encrypted by a key which is fresh, can I conclude the whole message is fresh?

Thanks for your help.